# Error "ATTENTION! No OpenCL or CUDA installation found" in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, amd-graphics, amdgpu, opencl

I want to run `hashcat` on Ubuntu 16.0, but it returns an error about OpenCl installation.

```
ATTENTION! No OpenCL or CUDA installation found.
```

The Graphic card used by system is:

```
lspci | grep VGA
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Oland GL [FirePro W2100]

glxinfo | grep Device
Device: AMD OLAND (DRM 2.50.0 / 4.15.0-58-generic, LLVM 6.0.0) (0x6608)

CPU:
product: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-1660 v3 @ 3.00GHz
```

I try to install few packages for drivers:

```
ocl-icd-libopencl1
```

but when used, return error:

```
 DRM_IOCTL_I915_GEM_APERTURE failed: No such file or directory
Assuming 131072kB available aperture size.
May lead to reduced performance or incorrect rendering.
get chip id failed: -1 [22]
param: 4, val: 0
DRM_IOCTL_I915_GEM_APERTURE failed: No such file or directory
Assuming 131072kB available aperture size.
May lead to reduced performance or incorrect rendering.
get chip id failed: -1 [22]
param: 4, val: 0
beignet-opencl-icd: no supported GPU found, this is probably the wrong opencl-icd package for this hardware
(If you have multiple ICDs installed and OpenCL works, you can ignore this message)
clGetDeviceIDs(): CL_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND

clGetDeviceIDs(): CL_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND
```

When I install **RadeonOpenCompute (ROCm)**, it's still not working.
Is there a solution?